# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an api call in jquery but I am getting this error 
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.ontraport.com/1/objects?objectID=5&start=50. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

But in firebug I can see my request header

```
Accept : */*
Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language : en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Allow-Orig... : *
Api-Appid : 2_z0j1
Api-Key : 2AsywN80
Host :api.ontraport.com
Origin: https://ruby-on-rails-amankumarglobussoft.c9users.io
Referer : https://ruby-on-rails-amankumarglobussoft.c9users.io/aman
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is sent from the server. And you shouldn't let the world know you API key.

Answer (score 0):

You just check [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

The dataType of `json` doesn't support cross-origin requests for security reasons. Try `jsonp` (JSON with padding) instead.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com
```

Where `http://www.example.com` is your website address.

You need the remote site to allow your site to access AJAX responses client side.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is there i guess?

Comment: are you get this issue from rails? if you get this issue from rails you can silmply solve some gem..i will tell you..

Comment: i am not the OP and OP has not put any response on your answer.

Comment: The dataType of json doesn't support cross-origin requests for security reasons. Try jsonp (JSON with padding) instead.

Comment: what you mean @Jai

Comment: @karthicknagarajan I am not sure about that I have given `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` Still I am getting this error. I debug in fiddler I think it not taking the header request in ajax.

Comment: Are you try to change your Datatype?